# Loading old boot logo even after flashing with custom rom MiUi pro 10. TWRP

Tags: android, miui

I installed custom MiUi Rom flashed with TWRP . Phone is Coolpad Note 3 Running with marshmallow Cool Ui . Flashed with MiUi Pro V10 with the help of TWRP Recovery. Installation was successful but when I try booting the phone it is still loading old boot logo ( Coolpad Logo ) instead of MI logo.

Before installation I wiped out ( Dalvick Cache, Data, Cache , Internal memory everything ) even though it is still showing old boot logo and after loading MiUi Rom..

How to force the boot to load MI branding logo instead of old Coolpad Logo.

How to change boot logo with custom logo ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is absolutely no relation to programming given.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change boot.img vai adb commands or via app but it is very tedious process i wouldnt recommend it but if you wanna do it here is [link](https://davinci-michelangelo-os.com/2017/01/22/edit-init-rc-android/)!

Comment: I solved the issue with Flashing Stock ROM with the help of SP FlashTool. Thank You.